# How to use LESS in eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, css, less

I want to use LESS in my eclipse. I mean that like when we make a CSS file it shows its intellisense and its syntax highlighting, etc. I want the same thing with LESS. Can you suggest me its update site? I tried [http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/update/](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Esimonet/soft/ow/update/) but when I try to install it it gives me the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
> not be found.   Software being installed: LESS 1.0.17
> (net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less.feature.feature.group 1.0.17)
>
> Missing
> requirement: net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less 1.0.17 (net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less
> 1.0.17) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.xtext 2.2.1' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> ```
>     From: LESS 1.0.17 (net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less.feature.feature.group 1.0.17)
>     To: net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less [1.0.17]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed Xtext?

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

It looks like Eclipse wants you to install Xtext as a requirement for the LESS plugin